# How do I postion both component on the far left and right and inline in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How do I postion both component on the far left and right and inline in react? the create button just cant go inline and to the right.

```
<div className="card-header">
    <div className="col-6">
        <h5>Products Category</h5>
    </div>
    <div className="btn-popup col-6 pull-right">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onOpenModal} data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="test" data-target="#exampleModal">Create</button>
        <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} >
            <AddDiscount/>
        </Modal>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: ri]

Comment: Have you tried `text-right` instead of `pull-right`?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it by adding a row

```
<div className="card-header">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-6">
      <h5>Discount</h5>
    </div>
    <div className=" btn-popup col-6 text-right">
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onOpenModal} data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="test" data-target="#exampleModal">Create</button>
    <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} >
      <AddDiscount/>
    </Modal>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```